# Private Methods in ObjC++

Tags: iphone, objective-c++

I need to rename a ObjC Class Implementation File into *.mm, because I'm using a 
C++ Framework (Box2D). After renaming the file and setting the Filetype to  "sourcecode.cpp.objcpp" my following declaration of private methods produces some errors like:

> error: expected identifier before 'private'

The declaration of  methods:

```
@interface GameplayLayer(private)
 - (void)spawnTick:(ccTime)delta;
 - (void)pushSpawnTick;
@end
```

How can I use declarations of private methods in ObjC++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably because `private` is a keyword in C++. You can either change it to something else like `hidden` or leave the category name empty (this is called a 'class continuation', you can [read more about it by searching in this article](http://theocacao.com/document.page/516/).)

Answer (score 3):

this is the way I declare my private methods in Obj-C
basically is just creating a category with no name in the .m
hope this helps

```
//this is A.h

@interface A

- (void) publicMethod1;

@end



//this is A.m

@interface A ()

- (void) privateMethod1;

@end

@implementation A

- (void) publicMethod1
{
    //foo
}

- (void) privateMethod1
{
    //foo
}

@end
```